# Resolve Error: typescript with invalid interface loaded as resolver ESLint

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm having ESLint in my project and getting an error `Resolve Error: typescript with invalid interface loaded  as resolver : import-no-restricted-paths` when I add the rule `import/no-restricted-paths`

[image: Error]

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*",
        "./generated/**/*"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6"
        ],
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "declaration": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "outDir": "./dist/js",
        "paths": {
            "@generated/*": ["../generated/*"],
            "api": ["lib/api"],
            "api/*": ["lib/api/*"],
            "asset/*": ["lib/asset/*"],
            "base/*": ["lib/base/*"]
        },
        // Rules
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true
    }
}
```

*.eslint.json*

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true
    },
    settings: {
        "import/parsers": {
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
        },
        "import/resolver": {
            "typescript": {
                paths: "./tsconfig.json",
                alwaysTryTypes: true
            }
        },
    },
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: {
        tsconfigRootDir: ".",
        sourceType: "module",
        project: "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    extends: [
        "plugin:import/recommended",
        "plugin:import/typescript"
    ],
    plugins: [
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "import"
    ],
    overrides: [
        {
            files: [
                "src/_migration/**"
            ],
            rules: {
                "import/no-restricted-paths": [
                    "error",
                    {
                        basePath: "./src",
                        zones: [
                            { target: "./_migration", from: "./", except: ['./_migration'] }
                        ],
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
    ],
    rules: {
        "import/no-unresolved": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/typedef": [
            "error",
            {
                parameter: true
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: I fixed this by deleting the lockfile and node_modules and reinstalling everything.

Comment: restarting vscode helped in my case 

Comment: Mine was resolved by restarting VS code also, wasted a couple of hours on this 

Comment: This kind of BS happens to me so often, I always restart VSCode before trying anything else. That works 95% of the time.

Comment: For new comers, check package.json if eslint-import-resolver-typescript is installed and if it's not, run: npm install eslint-import-resolver-typescript --save-dev

Answer (score 78):

This seemed to do the trick for me.

```sh
npm install -D eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

I don't want to delete `package-lock.json` because I know from experience that doing so causes problems for my current project.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Installed this package as instructed, then did `cmd`+`shift`+`p` in VSCode to find and run `ESLint: Restart ESLint Server`. Errors didn't come back after that! No restart required when I did this, but if the errors come back, might be worth trying just as a sanity check

Comment: It works, but why?

Answer (score 25):

For me, it was just enough to restart the eslint server.
On Visual Studio Code, you can do it with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and start typing:

```
>eslint: restart eslint server
```

Comment: Same for me. I was getting the error in IntelliJ, and a quick restart fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to `.eslintrc` solved it for me.

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
    }
  }
}
```